# Increase the heap of all JUNITS in eclipse

Tags: java, junit

I know I can configure heap size for individual junit test class while executing from eclipse.

Any idea how to configure the heap size to be applicable for all the JUNIT test classes with single time configuration.

Comment: It seems a bit contradicting: do you want to increase the heap for **all** unit tests or just **some** unit tests?

Comment: @mthmulders : All Junits with single configuration

Comment: I think (s)he means: **individual** heap size **for every** test case.

Answer (score 0):

Run all tests with `mvn clean test` with configured plugin that increases memory:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <forkMode>pertest</forkMode>
    <argLine>-Xms512m -Xmx512m</argLine>
    <testFailureIgnore>false</testFailureIgnore>
    <skip>false</skip>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This goal can be run within Eclipse.

Comment: I'm looking out the similar kind when you run from eclipse , say it is helpful for debug too..

Comment: Yes, this is the way. Add Maven to your project, and run the goal from Eclipse.